# I want to trigger this jQuery on 1000px or less. Can I do that with PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using this jquery to move towards a map after a selection with . I want to only do it when the browser is less than 1000px but the layout shifts to a top down layout.

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $( ".mapjumpul li:nth-last-child(2)" ).append("<a id='mapjump2'></a>");
    });
```

Comment: You would do that with Jquery, not PHP.

Comment: PHP can't do anything client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with JQuery

```
<script>
      var screen = $(window)    
        if (screen.width < 1000) {
             $( ".mapjumpul li:nth-last-child(2)" ).append("<a id='mapjump2'></a>");
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

U should be able to do this with mediaqueries as well :

```
#mapjump2 {
    display : none;
}    

@media (min-height: 1000px) {
   #mapjump2 {
      display : inline;
   }
}
```